# Left pop up spoiling my Website Layout

Tags: html, css, jsp

Hi recently I faced a problem in which left pop that is (add of related searches) on my website is spoiling the layout specially in internet explorer 11 when I inspect the element I found it is modifying my client side code like css as follows

```
<body style="margin-left: 160px !important;">
```

Is it possible to sniff internet explorer and then write some css or js code so pop will not be able to destroy my layout?

Comment: Sounds like you use free webhosting that injects ads into your HTML.  The only solution is to shell out some money and buy better hosting.

Answer (score 0):

The best resolution would be to pay for web hosting and not use free services that put ads on your site! - Shop around! Hosting can be very cheap. There isn't really a way around stopping the margin-left. You could potentially try a small amount of jQuery/javascript to change the css onload of the page. So quickly it would be something like in jQuery

```
$(body).css("margin-left","0px");
```

I hope this helps but it is not a guaranteed fix!